# elastic beanstalk environment health in warning state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, warnings, root

My environment state has changed from an Ok state to a Warning state hours after the launch of the instance. When I checked for causes it is showing that "**100% of the root file system is in use.0MB free**".Instance health is OK and none of the metrics seems odd. Is there a way to resolve the issue and know why the root system filled up so fast? Below is the image of the environment.
[image]

Comment: Just go to EC2 console, select your instance, and click connect, and session manager. This should put you inside the instance assuming the login still works due to lack of space.

Comment: There an error displaying while I try to connect to the instance "Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect."

Comment: Don't use EC2 instance connect, but try with Session manager. Its different option.

Comment: I cannot use that either.                                                                                      
We weren't able to connect to your instance. Common reasons for this include:
1.SSM Agent isn't installed on the instance. You can install the agent on both Windows instances and Linux instances.
2.The required IAM instance profile isn't attached to the instance. You can attach a profile using AWS Systems Manager Quick Setup.
3.Session Manager setup is incomplete. For more information, see Session Manager Prerequisites.

Comment: If you don't want to reboot the instance, then take snapshot of your root volume, create new volume of it, and mount it on a new instance which you can ssh into.

Comment: Actually creating a new instance helped for some time and after a day or two, I am getting the same warning message for the new instance. Due to this particular error auto-scaling is not getting done smoothly. What I want to know is, what can I do in such situations to resolve the error?